# Sencha Touch and Phonegap (Media Plugin)

Tags: android, extjs, cordova, touch

in my project using Sencha Touch and Phonegap. I have tried to use Phonegap Media Plugin in Sencha Touch for reproduce a local file audio, but does not works.

This is my code:

```
Ext.application({    name: 'ApplicationName',
requires: ['Ext.MessageBox'],
launch: function() {
    console.log("launch");
    this.launched = true;
    this.mainLaunch();


},
mainLaunch: function() {
    //console.log('Device name: ' + device.name);
    if (!this.launched) {return;}
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
      fullscreen: true,
      layout: {
          type: 'vbox',
          pack: 'center'
      },
      items: [
          {
              xtype : 'toolbar',
              docked: 'top',
              title : 'Ext.Audio'
          },
          {
              xtype: 'toolbar',
              docked: 'bottom',
              defaults: {
                  xtype: 'button',
                  handler: this.playAndroidNativeSound
              },
              items: [
                  { text: 'Play', flex: 1 }
              ]
          }
      ]
  });
},
playAndroidNativeSound: function() {
    var src = '/android_asset/www/src/crash.mp3';
    var media = new Media(src);
    media.play();
}});
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use `Ext.Audio` instead of `Ext.Media`?

Comment: Yes, but Ext.Audio does not work if compiles my app for Android (.apk)
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?200101-ST2-app-doesn-t-play-sounds-after-ST2-Native-Packaging-on-Kindle-Fire

Comment: Wow! it's really weird bug... and one more question have you tried to play your media after `deviceready` event fired?